# Getting rid of href in modal implementation

Tags: html, css

I am using a modal for displaying information on my site as people normally do. Modal I am using is completely written in css(no jQuery).When a link is clicked modal shows up and url changes as shown:

reminder.local/main.php#patient0

So, after that modal window is closed url becomes:

reminder.local/main.php#

The problem is, when back button is pressed it goes back to 
reminder.local/main.php#patient0
as expected and modal window pops up again, which is highly undesirable.

Any way around this..plzz let me know.

Example code for the modal:

```
 <a href="#text2" id="appoint">Next</a>

 <div class="lightbox" id="text2">
              <div class="box">
              <a class="close" href="#">X</a>
                <p class="title">Modal Window with Text</p>
                <div class="content">
                <form>
                  <input type="text" >Name <br>
                  <input type="password">Password <br><br>
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the url at all, you can change it so the modal opens from an `input`/`label` like so:

```css
input {
    display: none;
}
.lightbox {
    display: none;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
input:checked ~ .lightbox {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<input id="appoint" type="checkbox" />
<label for="appoint">Next</label>
<div class="lightbox" id="text2">
    <div class="box"> 
        <label for="appoint">X</label>
        <p class="title">Modal Window with Text</p>
        <div class="content">
            <form>
                <input type="text">Name
                <br>
                <input type="password">Password
                <br>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```